# Problem with git hook for updating site

Tags: git, githooks

I have set up a website on a server and use git to maintain it. For this reason I have created two git repositories, a bare one at `$HOME/site` to which I push and a non-bare one at `/var/www` which is supposed to pull from the bare repository every time a change is made.

In order to update the non-bare repository automatically, I have created and granted executon permission to a `post-update` git hook in the bare repository that contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www
git pull
```

However, after every push to the bare repository I can see the following on my terminal:

```
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Is there anything I have omitted or done wrong regarding this hook?

Comment: Did you init the repo at /var/www properly?

Comment: @crodjer How can I tell if my repo at /var/www is properly init'ed?

Comment: did you do run `git init` or `git clone` there?

Comment: @crodjer As far as I can remember `git clone`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. Add this line to your hook script before you do the git pull command:

```
unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)
```

This will unset all GIT_XXX_YYY environment variables.