Why does variable=$(cd any/path && git <any command>) not work in a git hook?
I am trying to format the committed source code inside my pre-commit hook, but I only want to execute this hook when I am in a specific repo. My "clever" way of checking I am in this repo is by checking whether there is a substring in my repo's remotes. All good until now.
However, my special repo, that requires formatting, has submodules and therefore I also want to be able to check the super repo's remotes when I am committing something from the context of a submodule. My solution is something like the below:
test=$(cd ../../; git remote -vv | grep 'my_special_repo')
echo $test
if [[ $test == *"my_special_repo"* ]]; then
    echo "This is a my_special_repo child submodule"
    echo "Commit should be formatted"
else
    exit 0
fi

This does not work. When I echo $test it is empty.
But this:
test=$(cd ../../; echo $PWD; git remote -vv | grep 'my_special_repo')
echo $test
if [[ $test == *"my_special_repo"* ]]; then
    echo "This is a my_special_repo child submodule"
    echo "Commit should be formatted"
else
    exit 0
fi

works fine.
I have found this fact that cd any/path && git any-command does not work from the context of a hook in other questions or comments in relevant questions/answers but without explanation.

Why does this not work?
Why does my workaround work?

PS: My git version is 2.41.0.windows.1

Those two snippets are identical.

If what you mean by "does not work" is "does not use the cd to change which repo it's looking at", that's because there are environment variables set during hook execution that override the default of referring to the current working directory to find the target to work on. But you really need to be much more specific about what the words "does not work" actually mean in this context in particular.

...well, there used to be such variables set -- apparently it's version-dependent now, so we'd need to know which specific version of git you're testing with.

BTW, I don't believe the claim that echo $test is empty. If nothing else it'll always contain the output from echo $PWD even if the git remote | grep had no output at all. (To avoid that, you'd want to make that echo "$PWD" >&2 so it isn't captured).

Apologies for my silly copy-paste mistake. It's fixed now.

@phd I want the context of my git command to be a parent directory rather than a subdir. Using git -C ../../ yields the exact same results, i.e. it works when just executed in git bash, but doesn't when it is part of the hook.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394777/7976758 Try unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars) Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+unset+environment+variables

@CharlesDuffy "does not work" mean, as mentioned in my question, that the variable test is empty, which I can only assume means that the git remote -vv command is executed at the submodule's context and therefore cannot find the substring I am testing for in the remote url.

The && means nothing will be run if cd fails. Your second snippet does not use && and runs the command unconditionally, but you can't be sure in which directory. (I don't think this is the problem, though.)

@phd got it right. This worked!

So @CharlesDuffy was right about environment variables. That's the culprit.

My 2nd question is still not answered, i.e. why my "workaround" of echoing the $PWD helps with this issue. Does referencing $PWD refresh the environment variables or something?

As phd said in his comment what was missing was this:
unset $(git rev-parse --local-env-vars)

before
test=$(cd ../../; git remote -vv | grep 'my_special_repo')

so that environment variables like GIT_DIR are reset and therefore the hook's script works as expected.
This is based on this answer.
PS: Now that it works I reworked my script to its more appropriate form (in my opinion):
test=$(git -C ../../ remote -vv | grep 'my_special_repo')

